# how to convert from integer to oracle.jbo.domain.Number in java/oracle ADF

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf

I have a problem that I need to know how to convert from integer to "oracle.jbo.domain.Number" in Java or Oracle ADF ??

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide us some [MCVE] so help you with your solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this not work?

```
int myInt = 5;
oracle.jbo.domain.Number n;
n = new oracle.jbo.domain.Number(myInt);
```